# How to remove a subelement/element in XML using PYTHON

Tags: python, xml

**Need some help to remove old(content[1]...[2]) "ns2:Comment" if there are 2 or more entries inside the XML file. I only need 1 "ns2:Comment" per instance.**

updated sample XML for better understanding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:Audit >
    <ns2:ProjectInfo>
        <ns2:Name></ns2:Name>
        <ns2:ProjectVersionId></ns2:ProjectVersionId>
        <ns2:WriteDate>2020-01-09</ns2:WriteDate>
    </ns2:ProjectInfo>
    <ns2:IssueList>
        <ns2:Issue instanceId="99999999999999" revision="0">
            <ns2:ManagerAuditTrail></ns2:ManagerAuditTrail>
            <ns2:ClientAuditTrail></ns2:ClientAuditTrail>
            <ns2:ThreadedComments>
                <ns2:Comment>
                    <ns2:Content>test</ns2:Content>
                    <ns2:Username>tester1</ns2:Username>
                    <ns2:Timestamp>2020-01-09</ns2:Timestamp>
                </ns2:Comment>
                <ns2:Comment>
                    <ns2:Content>test</ns2:Content>
                    <ns2:Username>tester2</ns2:Username>
                    <ns2:Timestamp>2020-01-09</ns2:Timestamp>
                </ns2:Comment>
            </ns2:ThreadedComments>
        </ns2:Issue>
        </ns2:Audit>
```

**SCRIPT I created:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('audit.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for x in root[1]:
    for thread in x:
        for content in thread:
            if content[1] is False and content[0] is True:
                pass
            else:
                thread.remove(content)

tree.write('audit1.xml')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML in your example is invalid (the order of start and closing tags does not match). I don't know where the ns2: namespace comes from, but if you want to load that in Etree, you'll have to define that namespace in the root node. For this string based example, I took out the ns2 namespaces.

```
sample = """<Audit>
<ProjectInfo>
<IssueList>

<Comment>
   <Content>test</Content>
   <Username>tester</Username>
   <Timestamp>2020-01-09</Timestamp>
</Comment>

<Comment>
   <Content>test1</Content>
   <Username>tester2</Username>
   <Timestamp>2020-01-09T</Timestamp>
</Comment>

</IssueList>
</ProjectInfo>
</Audit>"""
```

Importing that example (as a string) as follows, using lxml because it is faster:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring(sample)
root = tree.getroottree()
```

Now because the Comments you want to find are nested, instead of looping over them you could also use Xpath to get them. Then, you can select their parent node and remove the children of those with an index of 1 or higher.

```
commentlist = root.findall('//Comment')

for comment in commentlist[1:]:
   comment.getparent().remove(comment)

etree.tostring(tree)
```

You'll have to make some edits for namespacing and using the file, but this general principle works. If you have a lot of IssueList nodes of which you want to keep the first Comment, you can use Xpath to select all those, and then loop over the children, discarding every child but the first.

```
issuelist = root.findall('//Issuelist')

for issue in issuelist:
    first = True
    for child in issue.getchildren:
       if child.tag is 'Comment' and first is True: 
           First = false
           continue
       if child.tag is 'Comment' and first is False: 
           issue.remove(child)           

etree.tostring(tree)
```

Comment: thanks T. Altena. your inputs are highly appreciated. Already updated the sample XML above. btw, code is still not working and encountered below error: AttributeError: 'lxml.etree.xmlfile' object has no attribute 'findall'

Comment: I don't think you need to use xmlfile as an lxml extension, but you can use IO to stream the file to lxml. Like `with self.open(path) as fh:
                if is_xml:
                    parser = etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities = False)
                    return etree.parse(fh, parser).getroot()
                else:
                    return fh.read()`